# Access geolocation data using gomobile

Tags: go, geolocation, gomobile

Can I access the phone's geolocation using a native `gomobile` application?

I have seen experimental support for sensor data [here](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/mobile/exp/sensor), but nothing about the actual latitude, longitude of the device.

I have no prior experience in app development, and I am learning Go at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK there is no ready solution yet to access location on both Android and iOS in  a platform independent way. But in theory you could make separate packages using the `gomobile` tool to generate bindings for each platform.

For example on Android you would use something like:

```
import "Java/android/content/Context"
import "Java/android/location/LocationManager"

locationManager := ctx.GetSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE)
// nil check omitted.
location := locationManager.GetLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
// nil check omitted.
lat := location.GetLatitude()
lng := location.GetLongitude()
```

Where `ctx` is the context (an activity, service, etc.) that you receive in one of their lifecycle callbacks.

Also you can use other providers (network, fused).

Comment: out of curiosity - where these imports `Java/android/content/Context` and `Java/android/location/LocationManager` are coming from?